# Emacs: (next-line) and (previous-line) behaves incorrectly

Tags: emacs, cursor

I have added the following code in my `.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'previous-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'next-line)
```

After that I start Emacs and push `C-x C-b` to open `*Buffer List*` buffer. Then I push `C-x o` to make it active.

After these actions I try my new keybindings and they work strangely! `C-i` prints `No buttons!` at the bottom of the frame. `C-k` moves the point to the next line but prints `D` at the previous one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: C-i  is a special case: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabKey

Answer (score 0):

If you ask emacs to tell you what the keys are bound to, using `C-h c C-k RET` and `C-h c C-i RET` in your *Buffer List* buffer, you will be told that

> C-k runs the command Buffer-menu-delete
>
> TAB runs the command forward-button

Just because you bound those keys to other functions in the global key map does not mean that those bindings are active in any particular buffer, because there may be *other* keymaps in force that take precedence over the global map.

This is a large subject and you *must* proceed with caution (in particular, note that C-k is somewhat destructive: it marks the buffer for deletion - but it is conceivable that in a different buffer with a different mode, the map in force might make it much more destructive).

You can read about [keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings)  in the emacs manual.

Comment: So how do I add a really global keybindings, that would work in any buffer?

Comment: I don't think you can: the major/minor mode of the buffer can have its own keymap that overrides (generally small parts of) the global map. The only way that a key has a "universal" meaning is for all the modes to agree to leave the global mapping alone, i.e. it's a convention, not a law.